# Fill a block of elements in a matrix

Tags: julia

I am asked to solve this problem but I don't seem to find a way to do it. Anyone here would like to help me with this? Thanks in advance...

[image]

I tried to solve the problem this way but it didnt' work.

```
A = fill(0, 9, 9)
for i in A[3:5, 5:7]
    replace!(A, i => 2)
end
A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required function can be written in a one-liner.

```
insert_block(A,i,j,n) = A[i:i+2,j:j+2] .= n
```

For the given example, this yields:

```
A = fill(0, 9, 9);
insert_block(A,3,5,2);
A
9×9 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  2  2  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  2  2  0  0
 0  0  0  0  2  2  2  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```